# How to profile functions with name pattern using GCC/clang?

Tags: gcc, profiler, instrumentation

Option "-pg" for gcc instruments all the functions in the compiled units, which impose too much overhead for large projects. 
Is it possible to only instrument a subset of functions based on function name pattern for example?
There are suggestions like hooking all functions, but filtering passed-in function address and use addr2line to find out the function name. This is theoretically possible, but doesn't seem to be scalable.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use [Callgrind](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html), it is possible to not activate the profiling during all the execution, see options